# Changing question entirely?

Tags: discussion

So, I answered a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/mysql-server-busy-with-something/25780#25780) that the asker entirely changed the content of (after I answered; [edit history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/25777/revisions)), should that have been posted as a separate question?  Should (can?) we do anything about it (I suppose mods can merge but not ... anti-merge? split?)? Explain that he should post it as a separate question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory the asker [really shouldn't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7675/what-is-a-good-thing-to-do-when-the-implicit-meaning-of-a-question-that-i-asked). Some argue that [the answerer is responsible for updating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11108/do-you-down-vote-answers-that-become-wrong-after-a-question-is-changed), but I think that's in the case of less severe question edits; completely rewriting the question isn't a good idea. I left a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/mysql-server-busy-with-something#comment-34747) in this case asking him to post separately; you're right that mods can't split questions. When/if he does the original question can be rolled back so the answer makes sense again

---

**Edit**: It looks like he [did post a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25783/cant-drop-database) (albeit with less detail, for some reason), so I rolled back his original question and deleted the obsolete comments